# Variational formulation for the Kerr solution

Tags: general-relativity, angular-momentum, variational-principle, constrained-dynamics, kerr-metric

The critical points of the [Einstein-Hilbert action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action), if one allows axial symmetry, are Kerr-type solutions of the Einstein field equations, in which a parameter $\alpha$ interpreted as the angular velocity appears. The parameter $\alpha$, however, does not appear directly in the variational problem.

Is it possible to suitably modify the Einstein-Hilbert action so that the variational problem prescribes a particular value for $\alpha$? In other words, I'm searching for a new action $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\delta\mathcal{A}=0$ yields Euler equations whose solutions are Kerr-type with a prescribed value for the angular velocity.

**Update**: in a comment, Andrew said that a change of variables can make $\alpha$ appear in the action. How is that done?

Comment: If you start from Einstein-Hilbert action and extremize the lagrangian, you get Einstein's field equations and Kerr solution is a specific solution of these equations. Why do you need to modify this action? Or are you referring to a different action?

Comment: I'm searching for a *modification* of the EH action such that the solutions of the corresponding Euler equations are Kerr-type solutions with a prescribed vale for the angular velocity.

Comment: Why do you need this? $\alpha$ is the mass to angular momentum ratio and is just given by integration constants. Hence a solution of the field equations can describe all spacetimes with mass and angular momentum. Why do need a theory that will yield spacetimes with a particular mass to angular momentum ratio?

Comment: Well, if the piece of information about that ratio is contained in the variational problem, I can (try to) apply variational techniques to prove a certain kind of convergence of ther Kerr solution to other spacetimes, which ultimately is my goal.

Comment: You can do a change of variables so that $\alpha$ appears explicitly, then add a Lagrange multiplier constraint that fixes the value of $\alpha$.

Comment: A Lagrange multiplier is indeed what I wanted to use, but I don't see how a change of variables does the job of making $\alpha$ appear in the action.